# Test Grunt served pages in Virtualbox

Tags: node.js, networking, gruntjs, virtualbox

I'm developing some HTML-files using a lot of different libraries, but everything is compiled and served using grunt ('grunt serve'), which fires up my default browser and connects on 127.0.0.1:9000. I can copy/paste that URL into other browsers on my OS (Mac OS X) with no issues.

However, I also need to test in IE, where I normally use VirtualBox with browsers from modern.ie, but the URL is not available on those images (which makes perfect sense as it's a local IP). How do I make those URL's available to my VirtualBox images?

If I use my MAMP setup, I can access the URL's I've configured in my hosts file, but as I'm not using MAMP for this, that won't be an option.

Thanx in advance for any help!

/kim

Comment: So you want to access your node.js server which runs on Mac OS X from the a browser running in a virtual Windows machine on the same Mac, right? If yes, how did you set-up networking for the VirtualBox image? And if yes, this question has nothing to do with node.js and gruntjs - it's a simple networking/bridging problem.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The network is a host-only network at the moment.
I apologise if the question is in the wrong category, but to me the issue had something to with grunt/nodejs and wasn't simple at all.

Comment: Again, can you show us the way you configured [networking mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for your VirtualBox image?

Comment: * Adapter: (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5698334/adapter.png)
* DHCP: (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5698334/dhcp.png)

Comment: The images don't help me to solve your problem. You have to learn more about the already mentioned **networking modes** of VirtualBox. I'm not 100% sure, but I suppose [bridged network mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) is the best option for you. And of course you have to find out the IP address of your mac and replace '127.0.0.1' with this IP. On Linux the command is `ifconfig -a`, I don't know it for Mac.

Comment: [Find out IP-address on Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it to work, and as hgoebl said, it was a purely networking issue. Basically, I just followed this: http://naxoc.net/2013/10/22/windows-in-virtualbox-on-the-mac/ and everything works now.